# retrieve cd key from Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering a Windows XP License key](https://superuser.com/questions/32367/recovering-a-windows-xp-license-key)

My computer got a virus and is in a semi-usable state I lost the coa that corresponds to my Windows XP Install disc, however I still have the disc.

For re-installation I believe I will need the original key does any know, how I can retrieve this from my semi-working installation?

Comment: Use the Magical Jellybean finder: http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Answer (score 0):

I like the magical jellybean too. It works simply and easily and supports a wide variety of software using plugins. But right out of the box it'll show you your windows license key.

However, you must be able to run Windows to run this tool. It should work in Safe Mode if that is all you can get.